# Mongodb force insert as array

Tags: node.js, express, node-mongodb-native

I am using NodeJS, ExpressJS and MongoDB in this app. I have this bit of code:

```
router.post('/new', function(req, res) {
    var db = mongo.connect(MONGODB, function(err, database) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db = database;
        coll = db.collection('theusers');
        coll.insert(req.body, function(err, docs) {
            res.redirect('/users');
        });
    });
});
```

I'm passing the whole form to be inserted into my mongoDB's collection. Problem is, in this form, I have a multi-select form element.

```
<select data-required="true" name="vehiclemodel" multiple="" id="select-multi-input" class="form-control parsley-validated">
   <option name="model1">Model 1</option>
   <option name="model2">Model 2</option>
   <option name="model3">Model 3</option>
</select>
```

When only one item is selected, it's passed as a single object item but if we select multiple items, it's passed as array. Can I make it always send that particular submission as an array?

Comment: you could check - `if(!Array.isArray(req.body.vehiclemodel)){// assign a array with a single element and point req.body.vehiclemodel to it}`

Comment: This is sweet! Thanks for the suggestion @batscream

Answer (score 0):

I decided to tinker the logic on the template side (EJS) using

```
obj instanceof Array
```

If any better solutions are available, please do advice. I'm totally new to JS really :D